# HL7v2 to FHIR conversion default CodeSystem rules not working

Tags: json, hl7-fhir

In the HL7v2 to FHIR conversion [CodeSystem templates](https://github.com/microsoft/FHIR-Converter/tree/main/data/Templates/Hl7v2/CodeSystem), their default, i.e., "else" part in the if-then-else rule, is not working.

For example, for Patient.communication.language in the Resource/_Patient.liquid template, it has the following line to map a language code to a dictionary containing "code", "display", and "system".

```
{% include 'DataType/CWECodeableConcept' mapping: 'CodeSystem/Language', CWE: PID.15 -%}
```

In the CodeSystem/_Language.liquid template, if no matching code, it would output the input values.

```
    {% else -%}
    "code" : "{{ inCode }}",
    "display" : "{{ inCode }}",
    "system" : "",
    {% endif -%}
```

My case has PID.15="English" and it has no matching code. So, I expect the following output.

```
{
    "code" : "English",
    "display" : "English",
    "system" : "",
}
```

What happens is no output at all.

I also tried to add the following rule with no success.

```
    {% elsif inCode == 'English' -%}
    "code" : "{{ inCode }}",
    "display" : "{{ inCode }}",
    "system" : "",
```

I appears that CodeSystem/_Language.liquid does not take changes, nor does it handle no-matched codes with "else" condition. I tested the changes with the "FHIR Converter" extension in Visual Studio Code. What can I do to make the "else" condition in CodeSystem/_Language.liquid working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try this:

Make required changes in the [/CodeSystem/CodeSystem.json](https://github.com/microsoft/FHIR-Converter/blob/main/data/Templates/Hl7v2/CodeSystem/CodeSystem.json) file and that should work for you.

Also, update the VS Code extension to the latest version.

```json
 "CodeSystem/Language": {
            "A": {
                "code": "A's code", 
                "display": "A's display", 
                "system": "A's system"  
            },
            "__default__": {
                "code": "English",
                "display": "English",
                "system": "English"
            }
        },
```

#### Explanation:

The following statement is calling _DataType/*CWECodeableConcept* and passing 'CodeSystem/Language' to **mapping** parameter, and the value of PID.15 to the **CWE** parameter.

```json
{% include 'DataType/CWECodeableConcept' mapping: 'CodeSystem/Language', CWE: PID.15 -%}
```

Inside the _CWECodeableConcept.liquid, since **mapping** is populated it executes the *if* blocks, and not the *else* blocks.

```json
        {% if mapping -%}
            "code":"{{ CWE.1.Value | get_property: mapping, 'code' }}",
            "display":"{{ CWE.1.Value | get_property: mapping, 'display' }}",
            "system":"{{ CWE.1.Value | get_property: mapping, 'system' }}",
            "version":"{{ CWE.1.Value | get_property: mapping, 'version' }}",
        {% else -%}
            "code":"{{ CWE.1.Value }}",
            "display":"{{ CWE.2.Value }}",
            "system":"{{ CWE.3.Value }}",
            "version":"{{ CWE.7.Value }}",
        {% endif -%}
```

Inside the if block, *get_property* is used to fetch the code, display, system, and version for the mapping CodeSystem/Language corresponding to the value in CWE.(1|4|10).Value.

*get_property* uses the [/CodeSystem/CodeSystem.json](https://github.com/microsoft/FHIR-Converter/blob/main/data/Templates/Hl7v2/CodeSystem/CodeSystem.json) file, and not the individual files under the CodeSystem folder.

The behavior of *get_property* is documented [here](https://github.com/microsoft/FHIR-Converter/blob/main/docs/FiltersSummary.md#miscellaneous-filters). However, the documentation does not mention the name of the config file it uses. We are fixing the documentation in the next release.

For quicker turnaround, we recommend raising an issue on the FHIR converter [github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/FHIR-Converter/issues).

Comment: After I add the codes in /CodeSystem/CodeSystem.json as instructed, I got "Conversion Error - Process failed: The code system mapping file is invalid". If I remove the default setting, the error is gone. The problem is not fixed.

Comment: It's working after fixing matching braces.